# regex to get words inside parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have regex which prints between parenthesis, infact I need only specific parenthesis, i mean

```
car(skoda,audi)
bike(hayabusa)
```

I get output as: 
skoda
audi
hayabusa

To get the cars and bikes in parenthesis I used: `(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')`

But i need to get only cars in 'car(...)' specifically, what to do?

I tried something like: `(r'^car(\S+)\((.*)\)$')`

and i need only `skoda,audi` not hayabusa

I dont get output

Coding to use:

```
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []

with open('text1.txt') as f:
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')  #<=here i am using
    current_group = None

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = group_pattern.match(line)
        if m:    # this is a group definition line
            group_name, group_members = m.groups()
            groups[group_name].members.extend(group_members.split(','))
            current_group = group_name
        else:
            if (current_group is not None) and (len(line) > 0):
                groups[current_group].text.append(line)

for group_name, group in groups.items():
    print "%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members))
    print '\n'.join(group.text)
```

Comment: did you want to print `skoda`,`audi` strings separately?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think OP needs *prints between paranthesis but only specific paranthesis*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with your code?

```
^car(\S+)\((.*)\)$
```

The reason why your code matches the expected strings are,

- You need to change `(\S+)` to `(\S*)` because `\S+` does a greedy match.That is it matches upto the last. so no capturing will occur.

Finally your  regex would be,

```
^car(\S*)\((.*)\)$
```

Get your string which was present inside the group index 2.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """car(skoda,audi)
... bike(hayabusa)"""
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^car\S*\((.*)\)$', re.M)
>>> m = regex.findall(s)
>>> m
['skoda,audi']
```

Comment: Thnx, but,how can i use my re.compile stmt in my code.THE above code will get car the cars with car().

Comment: its fine but when i use over above code it prints `(skoda,audi)` instead of `car(skoda,audi)`

Comment: did you want to print the whole line?

Comment: not like that,if you look my above code,even with 2/more `car()` it will join and then print the output.Eg, `car(skoda)` and `car(bmw,benz)` it outputs as `car(skoda,bmw,benz)` but now i get only `(skoda,bmw,benz)`  it leaves the car.

Comment: Why don't you add the string `car` explicitly because it will give you the strings which are present only on the lines that starts with `car`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [**Positive Lookbehind &  Lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> The lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match.

```
(?<=^car\().*(?=\)$)
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pW9fT8/1)

OR get the matched group from index 1 using `findall`

```
^car\((.*)\)$
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/aQ3kN1/2)

---

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=^car\().*(?=\)$)')
test_str = u"car(skoda,audi)"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: thnx for answering ,i have posted a code in my question ,can i adapt your answer in that also?

Comment: sure that will be great but first try before posing the code.

Comment: Just use any above regex pattern to match each line.

Comment: i tried it ,it worked great, could i use in the above code also?

Comment: Sorry No idea about pytton code. The code is copied from the testing site. Just know a little about regex patten. Try it yourself.